# AngularJS1.6 ES6 component not displaying template

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

My folders are

```
client
 :src/
   :app/
     :common/
        :sidebar.module.js
        :sidebar.component.js
        :sidebar.controller.js
        :sidebar.html
   :root.module.js
   :root.component.js
   :root.html
 :index.html
```

my root.module.js is

```
import angular from 'angular';
import {sidebar} from './common/sidebar.module';

angular.module('cms', ['sidebar']);
```

The code inside my root.component.js is

```
import angular from 'angular';

const options = {
  templateUrl: './root.html'
}

angular.module('cms').component('root', options);
```

my root.html file is

```
<div class="root">
  <h1>Hi, I am Ayush Bahuguna</h1>
  <my-sidebar></my-sidebar>
</div>
```

my sidebar.module.js is

```
import angular from 'angular';

export const sidebar = angular.module('sidebar', []).name;
```

my sidebar.component.js is

```
import angular from 'angular';
import {sidebar} from './sidebar.module';
import {sidebarController} from './sidebar.controller';

const sidebar = {
  templateUrl: './sidebar.html',
  controller: 'sidebarController',
  controllerAs: 'ctrl'
}

sidebar.component('mySidebar', sidebar).name;
```

my sidebar.controller.js is

```
    function sidebarController(){
  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.items = [{item: 'Home', icon: 'home', status: '/'}, {item: 'New Post', icon: 'note_add', status: '/new'}]
}

export sidebarController;
```

my sidebar.html is

```
    <div class="sidebar">
  <ul class="sidebar-items">
    <li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items"><i class="material-icons">{{item.icon}}</i>&nbsp;{{item.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And my index.html is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="cms">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Blog Admin | Ayush Bahuguna</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
  <root></root>
  <!-- <script src="client/dist/js/plugins/tinymce/tinymce.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script> -->
  <script src="/dist/js/vendor.js"></script>
  <script src="/dist/js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here `vendor.js` and `app.js` are bundled files, and i have checked that nothing is wrong with them. They are loading perfectly, but my `<root></root>` isn't displaying anything, not even concerned about `<my-sidebar></my-sidebar>` because it's not even displaying the `h1` either.

Your help would be appreciated.

**EDIT** I have added more files. Also, in my server side code I have `app.use(express.static('client'))`

Comment: Does your folder structure contain `common` or `commons`? Because you show both. Also, have you defined `sidebar` as a module?

Comment: @Lex it's `common`. Sorry for the typo, and yes the `sidebar` is defined. but my `root` component isn't working at all because the `h1` in my `root.html` isn't displaying either

Comment: Please, provide all the relevant code. Where is root.component.js loaded ? How the one can know what is exported from common/sidebar.module ?

Comment: @estus hey, didn't know what you mean by "Where is root.component.js loaded?" and I have added more details to the question.

Comment: sidebar.component.js and root.component.js files aren't imported anywhere.

Comment: @estus but are they required to? Because I am defining the components on the modules sidebar and root, respectively, directly.

Comment: When using webpack, you have to import every file you want to use. Every file that is not imported isn't added to the bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS doesn't allow usage of relative paths as templateUrl (or atleast, not relative to the file you're putting the component in).

Instead, AngularJS resolves urls relative to a certain root (which can be configured iirc).

To solve this, I'm guessing you need to change your templateUrls as follows (guessing, as I can't tell for sure without a reproduction sample):

- `./root.html` => `./src/root.html`
- `./sidebar.html` => `./src/app/common/sidebar.html`

To demonstrate this, here are two plunkrs:

- not working (using your approach): https://plnkr.co/edit/1jfuuPP0ry0C7aFVvq06?p=preview
- working (using `./src/root.html`): https://plnkr.co/edit/uaKKro6IMiOzOz0xxiSY?p=preview

Other than that, there may be more issues but that's hard to tell without a full sample. As already mentioned in the comments, you do need to ensure all components are imported (you are either not loading them, or the code loading them isn't mentioned above). I generally would replace my component and module file like so:

root.module.js:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import {sidebar} from './common/sidebar.module';
import {rootComponentName, rootComponent} from './root.component';

angular.module('cms', ['sidebar'])
  .component(rootComponentName, rootComponent);
```

root.component.js

```
import angular from 'angular';

export const rootComponentName = 'root';
export const rootComponent = {
  templateUrl: './root.html'
}
```

And use a comparable approach for all your other modules.

Have a look at: https://github.com/frederikprijck/angularjs-webpack-starter/blob/master/src/app/contacts/contacts.module.ts regarding this approach.